# CMakeLists.txt with two subprojects with own CMakeLists.txt needs to create only one .so library which contains all

Tags: c++, g++, cmake, shared-libraries

I have three shared libraries: lib_1.so, lib_2.so and lib_3.so.
How do you create only one library with the name lib_all.so which are going to contain all three libraries?

I am trying to compile some source files which includes files from two subprojects/subdirectories and every subproject(2) have CMakeLists.txt but I want to create just one .so library, not three.

added 
I want that medium.so contains also libnoise.so and noiseutils.so, this is my CMakeLists.txt

```
project (map)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories (${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS python)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set (LIBNOISE_PATH ${MY_SOURCE_DIR}/libnoise)
set (LIBNOISEUTILS_PATH ${MY_SOURCE_DIR}/noiseutils)


add_subdirectory(libnoise)
add_subdirectory(noiseutils)

add_library (
    map SHARED  
    Wrapped.cpp
)


target_link_libraries (
    map
    boost_python
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

linoise and noiseutils are sudirectories with own CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Impossible, unless you have the sources for all three. If they were static libraries (.a), that'd work.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I have sources for all three, but when I do with cmake it creates three, I need one

Comment: @PaolaJ Then I suggest to reformulate your question.

Comment: @PeterHorvath I have reformulated question, any solution ? :)

Comment: @PaolaJ. To the reformulated version I haven't. :-) Maybe others.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot merge multiple shared libraries together into a single shared library. You also cannot merge multiple static libraries into a single static library.

What you can do however is merging multiple static libraries into a single shared library.

This is more a limitation of the underlying compiler and not one of CMake. Think of static libraries as you would of object files and of shared libraries as you would of executables: You can link multiple object files into a single executable, but the other permutations don't really work that well.

So in your case, use `add_library([...] STATIC)` for the `noise` and `noiseutils` libraries and `add_library([...] SHARED)` for the `medium` library. Then just add a `target_link_libraries(medium noise noiseutils)` to finish the job.